# Have an a tag with a link to another website inside my data.jsx array but it says link not found when I try to visit it on my local dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, jsx

I have a data.jsx page with multiple data arrays which I then map out on my component jsx file. one of the array entries is a link in an a tag but when I try to visit the link on my localdev it presents me with an error; problem is clearer below

here is part of my code for my data.jsx file:

```
id: 1, /* RESILIENT FITNESS */
    img: Work1,
    modalImg: WorkModal1,
    title: 'Website Build',
    details: [
      {
        icon: <FiFileText />,
        title: 'Project : ',
        desc: 'Website',
      },
      {
        icon: <FiUser />,
        title: 'Client : ',
        desc: 'Resilient Fitness',
      },
      {
        icon: <FaCode />,
        title: 'Language : ',
        desc: 'HTML, CSS, JavaScript',
      },
      {
        icon: <FiExternalLink />,
        title: 'Preview : ',
        desc: <a href="www.example.com">Click Here</a>,
      },
```

the last part has a desc with a preview so viewers can visit the website by 'clicking here'; however Im not sure if the issue is the code itself or its because Im working on my local dev (localhost:5173); this is the error when I actually try to click on 'Click Here' in the desc

[image]

I'm not sure if this is only happening as Im on a localhost; will the issue resolve itself once I deploy the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see you want to redirect on some page but the error shows the link is postfixed to localhost url. and hence it's giving you error.

Currently I've a solution is to call a function on click and in that function assign the url.

```
const somefn=()=>{
window.location.assign(url_goes_here);
}
```

Hope It'll help. Thanks

Comment: It helped! thanks so much, I put the function in a <span> tag in my data, so its 
<span onclick={somefn}>Click Here</span>

Do you know how I would make it so it opens the link on a new tab? like target=_blank for the a tag?

Comment: got this fixed with window.open instead of location.assign, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `www.example.com` with `http(s)://www.example.com`.

Answer (score -1):

try this if you want to open in new window just modify the anchor tag like this

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      CLick me
    </a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't work with an a tag, had to build a function with the window location assign then add an onclick to a span tag

Comment: @Santa if it in react dont forget to bind it under router tags.

Comment: any reason I can't make it in a <span> tag?

Comment: you can but then that span should be in a router tag as no routing work without router in react